# A tool similar to iftop for collecting total network usage per destination

Tags: osx, networking, network-monitor

The functionality I'm looking for is like this:

- I start it running in the background at the beginning of the day
- by the end of the day i have a summary of how many bytes were transferred to which destination

`iftop` is close to what I'm looking for

[image]

however, the totals there are per *connection*. Meaning, the totals per destination are zeroed once the connection is restarted. E.g. if I had been  receiving a stream for 30 minutes, it would show me say 500mb transferred, but once I restart the stream, it's back to 0mb, even though the destination is still the same.

OS is Mac but if there is something I can install on a router (or if there are routers with similar built-in features) I'd like to know this too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ntop` can be a little overkill but can be [compiled on Mac osx](http://www.ntop.org/ndpi/running-ntopng-and-ndpi-on-macosx/)